# loops and probabtily

Tags: java

i have to Have the computer compute all the possible ways three dice can be thrown: 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 2, 1 + 1 + 3, etc.  Add up each of these possibilities and see how many give nine as the result and how many give ten.

```
    public class prog209b
{
public static void main(String []args){

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do{
        for(int i = 1; i<=6; i++){
            count +=1;
            for(int y=1; y<=6; y++){
                count += 1;
                for(int x=1; x<=6; x++ ){

                    sum = i + y + x;

            }
        }

    }

  }while (sum == 10 && count == 27);{
      System.out.println("There are " +count +" ways to get ten");

}
}
}
```

Thats what i came up with but i can get it to work correctly at all. instead of giving me that theres 27 ways it gives me like 42. Obviously im not doing this correctly. Please help me before i have an aneurysm

Comment: What's the purpose of the `do/while` loop? Why do you have a block *after* the loop? Why are you only ever testing the `sum` at the end? Why are you incrementing `count` on *every* iteration of both the outer *and* middle loops?

Comment: This might seem nit-picky, but you don't really ask a question. While most people here can infer what your question might be, I'd just like to point out that sometimes... coming up with the right question is half the answer!

Comment: @admjwt: And in light of people spoiling the answer (and to give you extra work...), there is a recursive version.  It _may_ be logically cleaner, and _is_ more-easily extendable for the number of dice used.  Want to try to find it?  The terminating conditions will be interesting to find, at the least.

Comment: @admjwt - Or maybe find an actual estimation formula (rather than calculating all possibilities) - the total number of (all) possibilities is `sidesOnDie ^ numberOfDice`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not going to do your homework for you but:

- You don't need the `do`/`while` loop - why would you need to keep going once you'd found all the possibilities?
- You don't need to count all the possible dice rolls - you need to count how many give 9 as a total, and how many give 10. You could *either* do that with two variables, or you could make a method which took the "target" as a parameter
- You don't need the `sum` other than right in the innermost loop - all you need to do is find out whether the sum of the values is equal to one of your target values, and increment the appropriate counter...

Comment: So your saying put a if statement after the sum, and have it display when it equals 10? because i did that aswell and instead of just outputing it once it did it 25 times and still never gave me the correct amount of times

Comment: @admjwt: No - I'm saying that if it equals 10, you should increment the counter which represents "how many rolls add up to 10". You only want to print the result at the end, right?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "increment the counter"

Comment: @admjwt: You should have a counter variable which keep track of how many combinations you've seen adding up to 9, and another counter variable keeping track of how many combinations you've seen adding up to 10. When you add the dice up and they equal 10, increment ("add one to") the counter representing 10. To be honest, if this isn't enough help I would suggest you try to get some more help through your school - Stack Overflow is great for many things, but it feels like you could do with personal, face-to-face tuition at this point.

Comment: i would love to have face to face time, but this is an online class and i pretty much have to figure this all out on my own. I still dont know how i would implement the counter so it only counts up to nine. Oh well, thanks anyway i guess

Comment: @admjwt: You're not trying to make the counter only count up to 9. You're meant to add 1 to it every time you've got a combination of `x`, `y` and `i` such that `x + y + i == 9`. It's hard to work out which bit of that you're stuck on...

Answer (score 1):

Your `count += 1`s are in the wrong place and your `while (sum == 10 && count == 27)` makes no sense.

Comment: if you couldn't tell, i really am not sure what im doing here

Comment: Well think it through. You want to increment `count` each time you have a value for all three dice.

Answer (score 0):

```
int nine = 0
int ten = 0;
for(int i = 1; i<=6; i++){
   for(int y=1; y<=6; y++){
       for(int x=1; x<=6; x++ ){
          sum = i + y + x;
          if (sum == 9) nine++;
          if (sum == 10) ten++;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: From the tag description for homework: _Homework means the asker is requesting help with school homework. This lets potential answerers know that they should guide the student in solving the problem, rather than simply showing the complete answer._

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=6; i++){
    for(int y=1; y<=6; y++){
        for(int x=1; x<=6; x++ ){
             sum = i + y + x;
             if (sum == 10)
                 count++;
         }
    }
}
System.out.println("There are " + count + " ways to make 10");
```

Comment: I don't think presenting the code directly with no explanation is actually going to help the OP learn much.

Comment: @Jon Skeet actually his code actually helped me figure out what you meant by increment the count. While yes it cheating, i now actually know how to do this. im still fairly new to this java stuff. I didnt realize that thats how you would make a counter for this kind of problem. the only way to count that i could think of was just having it add 1 everytime it ran. i figured when it got to ten with that while statement it would only output how many times it ran. obviously that didnt work.

Comment: @admjwt: I still think it would have been better with explanation and *without* just giving you the code... by making you think it through instead.